# Selenium check if attribute contains part of a string in java

Tags: java, selenium, dom, xpath

So I have a webpage where the Id's of certain elements are generated dynamically with certain parts changing and certain parts being constant like so:

```
<div id= "xxxdiv" title= 'this title'>
  <p id = "xxxp">
  <table id = "xxxtable" title = 'not derp'>
         <div id = "yyyydiv">
           <table id = "yyytable" title= 'derp'>
             <table id = "yyytable2" title = 'not derp'>
               <table id = "zzztable" title = derp>
```

I'm trying to do some dynamic lookups on the page that can look for a given element where the id contains a known value. For instance, I do not always know how many nested elements might exist so the number that gets generated on the end can vary. So I would like to find an element by xpath where the @title = not derp and the @id contains yyy. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want only table or any element which meets your conditions ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@title='not derp' and contains(@id, 'yyy')]"));
```

will find the first element which matches your search criteria which would be `<table id = "yyytable2" title = 'not derp'>` of your HTML snippet.

Comment: Technically this finds the first `TABLE` element... not just the first element. Depends on what OP wants. It can be easily switched to `"//*[@title..."` to make it generic.

Comment: @JeffC True, I edited the answer in order to clarify.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful

Comment: I wasn't sure if contains(@id, 'yyy') looked for an element that contained a matching id or looked for an id that contained the provided text.

Answer (score 2):

There are a whole host of relational and logical operators you can use. In this case, assuming you're looking for the table element, you can use: `//table[@title='not derp' and contains(@id,'yyyy')]`

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to find an element by xpath where the @title = not derp and the @id contains yyy

I would suggest you `cssSelector` instead, because using `By.cssSelector()` to locate an element is much faster than `By.xpath()` in performance. So you should try as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table[id *= 'yyy'][title = 'not derp']"));
```

Comment: CSS selector faster than xpath? Is there any proof for that claim?